# Why can't I use in with an if condition

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
x=rnorm(100,0,1)
x
a=0
for(i in x){
  if(i in -1:1){
    a<-a+1
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Geeting error unexpected '}' in " }"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I changed the condition in the `if` statement. Is this what you want?

```
x=rnorm(100,0,1)
x
a = 0
for(i in x){
  if(i > -1 & i < 1){
    a <- a + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but can't we use "in" with if condition?

Comment: No. `in` is usually used with the for loop. And it has nothing to do with value comparison.

Comment: If you want to check whether a value is found within a vector (in your case the `i` within `-1:1`), you need to use `%in%`. But this does not check if a value is within the value range -1 to 1, just if it is one of the values of the vector `-1:1` (so either -1, 0 or 1).